# Warning:incomplete implementation of class - iphone sdk warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

here is my code

```
//
//  SecondViewController.m
//
//  Created by tushar chutani on 11-05-16.
//  Copyright 2011 Fleetwood park secondary . All rights reserved.
//
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@implementation SecondViewController;

@synthesize titleForSong;
@synthesize bookDetailViewController;


-(void)viewDidLoad{
[titleForSong becomeFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction)save{
NSLog(@"save is killed");


}


-(IBAction)cancel
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


@end
```

.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController.h"
@class iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
UITextField *titleForSong;  
sqlite3 *db;
iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController *bookDetailViewController;  
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController     *bookDetailViewController;
-(NSString *)filePath;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *titleForSong;
-(IBAction)cancel;
-(IBAction)save;
@end
```

Comment: This question is too open-ended.

Comment: it has been solved thanks for commentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't implement `-(NSString *)filePath;`